# SWT plotting large data on a canvas

Tags: swt

Hi I have to plot large amount of data inside the canvas. But this eats up the jvm memory allocated when i directly plot it on the canvas.So I want to plot few data at a time and clear the non user visible data from the canvas. Can I resize or remove the part of canvas such that area which is not visible to user will be removed and new dta should be plotted at the bottom of the canvas and upper part should be removed while scrolling.

pardon my english and sorry I dint know how to put this problem in better words.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas ignores everything that is painted outside its visible area. So there is no need for you to clear anything. Whenever a previously invisible part of the canvas becomes visible (e.g. by scrolling), it is repainted; and the parts that become invisible will be "forgotten". The paint event contains the rectangle that needs to be painted. So you could optimize your code by only painting data that lies within that rectangle. In any case, it's not the canvas that is eating up your memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so we can draw data on virtual locations which are not visible in the canvas and translate them while scrolling. Does this data consume memory for drawing in such virtual locations?? we have a time scale which consumes lots of memory(it couldnt be optimised) which is say 10,000 pixels and my canvas is 1000 pixels can I draw this rest of timescale outside the canvas area and translate it on to the canvas while scrolling. (considering the canvas is fixed at a location and doesnt move. Forgot to mention the canvas i am talking about is org.eclipse.draw2d.FigureCanvas )

Comment: Wait, so you are using Draw2d to draw your data? That makes a lot of difference. If yes, then your memory problem is likely caused by creating a lot of figures. The canvas itself should only use a fixed amount of memory, no matter how much to paint on it.

Comment: First of all, you should verify that the number of figures is actually causing your memory problem. How many are you creating? I think it would have to be a huge amount to have a significant impact on memory consumption.

Comment: yes the figures consume lot of memory. I want them to be plotted serially on the canvas but couldnt because of the memory issue. Now I want to plot them such a way that as when I scroll down the canvas should be expanded by say x pixels (height)amount and new data should be plotted there at the same time some part say x pixels (height) should be removed from the top of the canvas. I tried this but couldnt achieve i tried this with setting the bounds but that wouldnt make any difference as the setting the bounds will merely shift the location of the canvas to the new position alongwithits data.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything when scrolling. You describe the whole graphical content (not just the currently visible part) using the figures, and the `FigureCanvas` automatically paints the portion that is currently visible in its viewport.